# php namespaces falling back to global using variable not working

Tags: php, namespaces

I have two files:

index.php

```
$a = "a";
```

namespace.php

```
namespace tom\anderson\s;
include 'index.php';


echo \$a;
```

This does not work and outputs this error message: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$a' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in...`

Why is this? Any references to official documentation would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php):

> PHP Namespaces provide a way in which to group related classes, interfaces, functions and constants.

As you are using to group variables, the error is being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Variables do no belong to a namespace and exist in the global scope.
To get program work slash before $a must be removed.

From php documentation. Defining namespaces
*Although any valid PHP code can be contained within a namespace, only the following types of code are affected by namespaces: classes (including abstracts and traits), interfaces, functions and constants.* 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php